# How to add foreach php to return html

Tags: php, html

I have function that returns html code
And I want to add foreach loop to return code

I try this code but I get an error

```
return '<section class="n-hero-section-two rebuild" ' . str_replace('\\', "", $bg_img) . '>
    ...
      <div class="n-hero-two-box">
         <div class="n-hero-two-main-text">
            ' . $main_section_tagline .'
            ' . $main_section_title . ' 
         </div>
         <div class="n-hero-two-form-cat">
            ...
            <div id="search-headline" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel">
            ...
                <ul class="live-filter live-filter-nd">'
                    // I want to add foreach here
                    foreach (array_combine($allprofessionsLinks, $allprofessions) as $allprofessionsLinks => $allprofessions) {
                        // echo '<option value="' . $allprofessionsLinks . '">' . $allprofessions . '</option>';
                        echo"<li><a href=" . get_home_url() ."/candidates/?cand-headline=".$allprofessionsLinks.">" . $allprofessions . "</a></li>";
                    }
                    
                '</ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</section>';
```

Comment: Run foreach() before the return and instead of echo put the output into a string. Add that string in the place where the foreach() is now.

Comment: I would recommend passing your data to your template, where you can render your HTML and use PHP tags to have dynamic output

Comment: Instead of returning immediately, assign the string to a variable then inside the loop concatenate the options to your variable and return the variable at the end of the function.

Comment: W3Schools has a good example on using foreach loops in PHP to output HTML [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add foreach result to string and add string to return

```
$live_search_result = '';
        foreach (array_combine($allprofessionsLinks, $allprofessions) as $allprofessionsLinks => $allprofessions) {
       
        $live_search_result = $live_search_result . "<li><a href=" . get_home_url() ."/candidates/?cand-headline=".$allprofessionsLinks.">" . $allprofessions . "</a></li>";
    }
```

And add $live_search_result string to result

```
<ul class="my-custom-class">'
    . $live_search_result .
   '</ul>
```